# Building package in monorepo with shared webpack.config creates dist outside package

Tags: webpack, monorepo, yarn-workspaces, yarn-v2

I am preparing a monorepo setup which will be used to combine multiple related repositories in one larger repo.
At the same time Yarn version 3.6.x is installed in the new repo, compared to v1 in the old repos. To reduce the maintenance of configuration files i try to maximise the use of shared configs. These shared configs are placed in a separate workspace `configs`. The to be migrated repos will be moved to the workspace `packages`.

Simplified the directorystructure of the monorepo repository is

```
.
├── package.json
├── configs
│   ├── babel
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   └── babel.config.js
│   │   └── package.json
│   ├── typescript
│   │   ├── config
│   │   │   └── tsconfig.json
│   │   └── package.json
│   └── webpack
│       ├── config
│       │   └── webpack.config.js
│       └── package.json
├── packages
    └── cancel
        ├── --webpack.config.js
        ├── src
        │   ├── index.tsx
        └── webpack.config.js
```

Where the package.json in the root of the project contains

```
{
    "name": "@myorg/monorepo",
    "version": "1.33.0",
    "private": true,
    "description": "demo",
    "repository": {
        "type": "git",
        "url": "https://gitlab.myorg.nl/myorg/mijn-team/frontends/monorepo"
    },
    "license": "ISC",
    "scripts": {
        "preinstall": "npx only-allow yarn && husky install",
        "build": "yarn workspaces foreach --parallel --include '**' run build"
    },
    "config": {
        "commitizen": {
            "path": "./node_modules/cz-conventional-changelog"
        }
    },
    "resolutions": {
        "babel-eslint-parser/semver": "^7.3.2"
    },
    "workspaces": [
        "packages/**",
        "configs/**"
    ],
    "devDependencies": {
        "commitizen": "^4.3.0",
        "cz-conventional-changelog": "^3.3.0",
        "husky": "^8.0.3"
    },
    "engines": {
        "node": "18"
    },
    "packageManager": "yarn@3.6.0",
    "team": "Mijn ORG",
    "title": "Monorepo setup"
}
```

The package.json in `packages/cancel` contains the script

```
"scripts": {
        "build": "webpack --mode=production"
}
```

The Webpack configuration in `packages/cancel` is loaded from `/configs/webpack` in `webpack.config.js`

```
const globalConfig = require('@myorg/webpackconfig/config/webpack.config.js');

module.exports = globalConfig ;
```

When executing `yarn build` the package in `packages/cancel` is build, but not in `packages/cancel/dist` but instead in `configs/webpack/config/dist`. Also when adding the statement below to the webpack config the current dir `configs/webpack/config` is logged thought the build is initiated from `packages/cancel`

```
console.log(`curdir ${__dirname}`)
```

All goes fine when i do copy the `configs/webpack/config/webpack.config.js` to `pakages/cancel` but this will result in multiple redundant copies of the same webpack config in the monorepo.

Answer (score 0):

`__dirname` is an environment variable that tells you the absolute path of the directory containing the currently executing file. In this specific case the location of the, through `packages/cancel/webpack.config.js`, location of the executed `webpack.config.js` is ` configs/webpack/config.

The `__dirname` Nodejs environment variable was used to set the entry in the `webpack.config.js`.

```
        entry: {
            index: path.resolve(__dirname, './src/index.tsx'),
        },
```

Therefore the location of `dist` was the same for each package. This is resolved by passing the value of `$INIT_CWD` in `curdir` which holds the directory when executing the run command.

```
"build": "webpack --config webpack.config.js --mode=production --env=curdir=$INIT_CWD",
```

And using this env variable to resolve the entry

```
    entry: {
      index: path.resolve(env.curdir, './src/index.tsx'),
    },
```

It can also be done by only changing the `webpack.config.js` by reading the INIT_CWD from `process.env.INIT_CWD`

```
    entry: {
      index: path.resolve(process.env.INIT_CWD, './src/index.tsx'),
    },
```